ng test --code-coverage-exclude not working
My use case is to generate coverage report for Angular project by excluding certain files, I've excluded those files in angular.json it's working as expected. However I'm looking to exclude them via ng test command
ng test project --source-map=false --browsers=Chrome --code-coverage --watch=true --progress=true --code-coverage-exclude=['projects/folder1/template1/**']

Above command isn't working.

As stated in Angular docs about Angular CLI, to specify array options to the CLI, the syntax is to provide the argument name and then the options separated by space. Hence your command would be
ng test project --source-map=false --browsers=Chrome \
  --code-coverage --watch=true --progress=true \
  --code-coverage-exclude 'projects/folder1/template1/**'

And you could add more arguments to --code-coverage-exclude by:

Separating values with spaces

ng test project \
  --code-coverage-exclude 'projects/folder1/template1/**' 'projects/folder1/template2/**'


Repeating argument name / argument value pairs

ng test project \
  --code-coverage-exclude 'projects/folder1/template1/**' \
  --code-coverage-exclude 'projects/folder1/template2/**'


Thank you so much, it works! Just one minor correction we need to remove for projects path. ng test project 
--code-coverage-exclude projects/folder1/template1/** projects/folder1/template2/**
